# Charging an iPhone 4S with a Samsung USB charger

Tags: usb, battery, iphone, charging

I have an iPhone 4S that I charge via a USB cable (plugged into my laptop). I also have a [Samsung USB charger](http://gsm-nova.com/image/cache/data/chargers/samsung/ETA0U80EBEG-samsung-original-charger-usb-cable-3-500x500.jpg) with the following specifications: 5.0 V and 1.0 A.

**Is it safe to plug my Apple USB cable into the Samsung charger and charge my iPhone like this?**

Should I be worried that it might blow up?

If I use a charger with more/less Amperes, does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I personally wouldn't attach a non A-branded charger to my iPhone, theoretically if the charger delivers 5V and does it on a USB connector, it really doesn't matter from where the power comes.

The more amps the faster your iPhone will charge.  I've been charging my iPhone with my iPad charger for years without any problems.

Currently Apple has 3 types of USB chargers

- iPhone charger: 5 volts 1 amp = 5 watt
- iPad 'old' type: 5 volts 2 amp = 10 watt
- iPad 'new' type (from iPad 4 on): 5 volts 2.4 amp = 12 watt

The Samsung 1 amp charger you're talking about will give you the same results as the original iPhone charger.

Comment: That's a great answer